# Will adding more trackers speed up a torrent?

Tags: bittorrent

If I add more trackers to my trackers tab in uTorrent will it speed up my download?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Trackers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BitTorrent_tracker) assist in allowing peers to connect to each other. By adding more trackers, you should have more options for peers to connect to. Therefore, there is a good chance that adding more trackers will improve download speeds.

Comment: **Note:** You can't just add trackers. You have to make sure that that tracker also has that same torrent.

Comment: @Nifle: what happens if I had a tracker to a torrent, and that tracker does not have that torrent?

Comment: @JNat - Nothing at all probably. May depend on the torrent client you use, but I doubt anything at all will happen.

Comment: What happens is that either the tracker starts tracking that torrent or it refuses to do so. For example, `opentracker` will, by default, track anything that’s thrown at it. The tracker doesn’t need to know the torrent file beforehand. So no, you can indeed just add trackers.

Answer (score 1):

According to this [article](http://ktetch.co.uk/2014/01/bittorrent-tracker-madness/), it helps but it also put unnecessary burden to the trackers. So if you care about the torrent community it is wise if you just use one tracker and turn on your DHT.

Comment: Well, while it may technically be a valid point, complaining about less than 100 MBit/s average bandwidth usage is just silly.

Comment: No matter how small it is it's still a waste bandwidth though.

Answer (score -1):

following the link [article torrent trackers](http://tinytorrent.net/best-torrent-tracker-list-updated/) I was able to download 20gb torrent file within 5 minutes, So adding trackers actually works.