# Is there an automatic way to add trackers to a torrent?

Tags: bittorrent, utorrent

As explained by [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/289371/will-adding-more-trackers-speed-up-a-torrent/289373#289373), adding trackers to torrents may speed up their download, as well as allow you to share the files with more peers.

Is there some way by which I can automatically add a list of trackers to every torrent I add on my client (which is uTorrent), besides the ones embedded in the .torrent file?
Or do I need to do this manually for each torrent?

Comment: Is the torrent present on all those trackers? Adding a bunch of useless trackers to every torrent might not cause any problems, but it might slow down downloads as the client makes repeated useless requests to trackers that will then reply with a "torrent not found" error.

Comment: @Karan: ok, so maybe a way to provide a list, so that whenever I add a torrent to my client he asks me which trackers from that list I want to add?

Comment: You'll have to see if someone's coded an app for this, or make one yourself. Perhaps it might be easier to do this with the uTorrent WebUI, but again I don't know if a solution already exists. I think you can add trackers to multiple selected torrents in uTorrent, but that will remove other trackers that exist already.

Comment: @Karan: yes, you can add trackers to several torrents at once, but uTorrent overwrites the existing ones.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I remembered it doing.

Comment: I believe you can do this on qBitTorrent. There is an option to "automatically add these trackers to new downloads."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't. Do NOT AT ALL.

Unless someone else has already added the tracker, you won't find anyone. And if they've just added the tracker, guess what, you'll already see them on the tracker that came with it.

If you're really sure there's peers out there you're not seeing, then turn on DHT. It's that simple.

Just adding trackers however not only doesn't 'speed anything up' (trackers have NOTHING to do with speed, just like the number of phone books you have to look a phone number up doesn't make a conversation any faster) you're sending out more traffic, which means you've less to use for transfers.

You're also adding bandwidth and load to trackers, for no gain, so you're actually harming trackers.

Still think it's a good idea? (if you want to see the maths just from TPB putting 4 tracker on every torrent, I [did it here](http://ktetch.co.uk/2014/01/bittorrent-tracker-madness/). With 50M peers, it works out about 20Tb of useless duplicated data PER TRACKER, PER MONTH.

Comment: While for the most part you do not need to add trackers, in the case of dead torrents, or ancient torrents, sometimes you will actually have to look outside your networks to find a peer. I've had to do this on numerous occasions, even with my own files, like fonts I had done. You'd be surprised what other trackers carry. Especially outside highly turncated and regulated channels (not talking about piracy; just the loss of files or dumped for arbitrary reasons)

Answer (score 1):

There's no way actually.. and a single torrent that you download need a different tracker list.. so I suggest to you to download a torrent file, put in download, then take the hash code in the info with right click>copy.
Now you can find healtly trakers lists to put on.